# Why use a View as a parameter for onlick event in Android

Tags: android

I am new to the android and I follow video tutorials, but it does not describe why it uses `View` as a parameter in `onclick` event.

This is my TextView and Button.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Old String"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:onClick="textChange"
        android:text="Change" />
```

and this is the code for text change

```
  public void textChange (View vw) {

         TextView display = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         display.setText("New String");

     }
```

can someone explain the usage of **View vw** above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, The View object passed into the method is a reference to the widget(View) that was clicked.

And basically View class is root or Super class for all kind of Views in Android

Also can refer,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

To find out what view was clicked? In future better google docs - they can answer all questions of such type.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

We use **"View"** there because we can use this method from other views also like two buttons with parameter `android:onClick="myMethod"`, in this case you will have to check in the method on behalf of the view parameter that which button was pressed...